# int [] cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to use a 2D array for a gradebook method, where it has the student names, then the exam scores. In the class I have as follows.

```
private int numberOfStudents;    
private String [] studentName;
private int  examNumber;
private int [] examScores;
private int [][] gradebook;

public ExamAverage ()
{
numberOfStudents = 0;
studentName = new String[numberOfStudents];
examNumber = 0;
examScores = new int [numberOfStudents]; 
gradebook = new int [numberOfStudents][examScores];
```

Yet I get an error int[] cannot be converted to int.

Comment: So, what do you think the error means?

Comment: You have another serious problem here.  You are creating arrays of size zero.  You really need to set `numberOfStudents` and `numberOfExams` (or something like that) to a value other than zero, before you create the arrays `studentName`, `examScores` and `gradebook`; otherwise these arrays won't have room for any actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
gradebook = new int [numberOfStudents][examScores];
```

But `examScores` is an `int[]`. Array dimensions have to be an `int`, so `examScores` cannot be used as an array dimension (I can understand your confusion about the error, given how literal it is: it wants an `int` but you gave it an `int[]`).

Judging by your description I'm guessing you mean something more along the lines of:

```
gradebook = new int [numberOfStudents][numberOfExams];
```

Where `numberOfExams` is an `int` you'll need, containing the count of exams. Just a guess, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason! Was very useful info and added it to my notebook even haha. Glad you understood my confusion. You were a big help!

Answer (score 1):

`examScores` is an int[] array, and array size should be `int` so it gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you exactly what the problem is.

`examScores` is an `int array` but you're trying to use it as a single integer for how large you want the 2nd dimension of your array `gradebook` to be.

You probably want to use `examScores.length` or some number that indicates how many exam scores per student you want.