# int[] cannot be converted to int return statement

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am making a program where the method `kthDataValue` returns the kth data value when the data values are considered in sorted order. The error says that `int[]` cannot be converted to `int` with the `return` statement.

```
public static int kthDataValue(int[] tally, int k) {
    int[] array = new int[k];
    for (int x = 0; x < tally.length; x++) {
        if (tally[x] > 0) {
            for (int z = 0; z < tally[x]; z++)
                array[x] = x + 1;
        }
    }   
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Your method signature requires an `int` as return value, but you are returning an array of `int`s (`int[]`). Add the braces to the signature or return a single `int`... Depends on what it is supposed to return.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [int \[\] cannot be converted to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177770/int-cannot-be-converted-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration is saying return int, but you are returning int[] array. It's complete mismatch.

```
public static int kthDataValue(int[] tally, int k) {

 return array;
```

If the input array is already sorted then you can directly return kth element by array index . If the array not sorted then you can use quickSelect algorithm.